# Show Label for Simple Form After Hiding by Default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using `rails bootstrap` with `simple_form`. For most of my input fields, I'm only using placeholder text. I've commented out the line that adds labels to fields:

```
#initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    # b.use :label
    b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
    end
  end
```

I know I can manually remove a label in a view by adding `label: false`, but `label: true` doesn't work to add back in a label.

How do I add a label when my default setting is to not show it?

Answer (score 0):

Add another wrapper, instead manipulation default wrapper with your settings,

```
config.wrappers :placeholder_form, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
    end
```

when you want to use this wrapper for form, use

```
simple_form_for @user, wrapper: :placeholder_form
```

for default wrapper, do not pass wrapper attribute to simple_form_for